# How to search in a List of Java object

Tags: java, list, search, collections

I have a List of object and the list is very big. The object is

```
class Sample {
    String value1;
    String value2;
    String value3;
    String value4;
    String value5;
 }
```

Now I have to search for a specific value of an object in the list. Say if `value3=='three'`  I have to return those objects (My search is not always based on value3)

The list is

```
List<Sample> list = new ArrayList<Sample>();
```

What is the efficient way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: why you don't creat a List<String>? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: @Tichodroma He says he has a list of those objects.

Comment: @Tichodroma I think he means a `List<Sample>`, which is a list

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency for a LOT of objects, I would consider a heirarchy of sorted objects, then an efficent algorithm to skip over impossibilities.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can give a try to [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/).

There is a class [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) that allows you to select or filter items by custom [Predicate](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/Predicate.html).

Your code would be like this:

```
Predicate condition = new Predicate() {
   boolean evaluate(Object sample) {
        return ((Sample)sample).value3.equals("three");
   }
};
List result = CollectionUtils.select( list, condition );
```

**Update:**

In **java8**, using Lambdas and [StreamAPI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) this should be:

```
List<Sample> result = list.stream()
     .filter(item -> item.value3.equals("three"))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

much nicer!

Comment: The CollectionUtils method gives me this error : `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method stream()Ljava/util/stream/Stream; in class Ljava/util/List; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar` , and I can't use Lambdas as Android SDK doesn't support Java 8.

Comment: @Yankee getting the same issue. did you get it to work?

Comment: @ono I used the Java8 method, worked great. But remember you'll have to add some Java 8 specific dependencies in your Gradle file

Comment: @Yankee i have the gradle imports but im still getting it. you have these two right? `compileOptions {sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8}`

Comment: @ono Yes. These are in my build.gradle(Module:app) and there's `classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0'` in my build.gradle (project)

Comment: @Yankee turns out this was only happening on an emulator with Genymotion. Does it still happen for you on emulators?

Comment: @ono I never use emulators, I directly use a device.

Answer (score 52):

### Using Java 8

With [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29) you can simply convert your list to a [stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) allowing you to write:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

List<Sample> list = new ArrayList<Sample>();
List<Sample> result = list.stream()
    .filter(a -> Objects.equals(a.value3, "three"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that

- `a -> Objects.equals(a.value3, "three")` is a [lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)
- `result` is a `List` with a `Sample` type
- It's very fast, no cast at every iteration
- If your filter logic gets heavier, you can do `list.parallelStream()` instead of `list.stream()` ([read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible))

### Apache Commons

If you can't use Java 8, you can use [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) library and write:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate;

Collection result = CollectionUtils.select(list, new Predicate() {
     public boolean evaluate(Object a) {
         return Objects.equals(((Sample) a).value3, "three");
     }
 });

// If you need the results as a typed array:
Sample[] resultTyped = (Sample[]) result.toArray(new Sample[result.size()]);
```

Note that:

- There is a cast from `Object` to `Sample` at each iteration
- If you need your results to be typed as `Sample[]`, you need extra code (as shown in my sample)

---

Bonus: A [nice blog article](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/find-element-in-list/) talking about how to find element in list.

Comment: Well `a.value3.equals("three")` would look more natural, but your way is also "null safe", so keep that :D. Thanks for the update, but I still wonder why no one else noticed it. Since you're more into other languages (according to your tags) I can't/won't blame you, because String comparison might work differently there. But nevermind, it is fixed now.

Comment: @Tom "three".equals(((Sample) a).value3) would also work and is "null safe".

Comment: Also add `import java.util.Objects;`

Answer (score 5):

If you always search based on `value3`, you could store the objects in a Map:

```
Map<String, List<Sample>> map = new HashMap <>();
```

You can then populate the map with `key = value3` and value = list of Sample objects with that same `value3` property.

You can then query the map:

```
List<Sample> allSamplesWhereValue3IsDog = map.get("Dog");
```

Note: if no 2 `Sample` instances can have the same `value3`, you can simply use a `Map<String, Sample>`.

Comment: No.. My search is not always based on value3.. It can be based on any field in object

Comment: @Sun It is a matter of compromise between performance and memory foot print: maintaining one map per field will be faster but use more memory, looping over the list every time you need to search will be slower but use less memory.

Comment: Alternatively, if the structure of your object is flat (only String fields) you could have a look at Guava's table - I have never used it though.

Answer (score 3):

I modifie this list and add a List to the samples try this

Pseudocode

```
Sample {
   List<String> values;
   List<String> getList() {
   return values}
}



for(Sample s : list) {
   if(s.getString.getList.contains("three") {
      return s;
   }
}
```

Comment: My list is very Big.. i'm looking for a efficient search. is this the only possible way?

Comment: you could organize the values as a hashmap, to avoid check every entry in Sample...

Answer (score 0):

As your list is an `ArrayList`, it can be assumed that it is unsorted. Therefore, there is no way to search for your element that is faster than *O(n)*.

If you can, you should think about changing your list into a `Set` (with `HashSet` as implementation) with a specific `Comparator` for your sample class.

Another possibility would be to use a `HashMap`. You can add your data as `Sample` (please start class names with an uppercase letter) and use the string you want to search for as key. Then you could simply use

```
Sample samp = myMap.get(myKey);
```

If there can be multiple samples per key, use `Map<String, List<Sample>>`, otherwise use `Map<String, Sample>`. **If you use multiple keys, you will have to create multiple maps that hold the same dataset.** As they all point to the same objects, space shouldn't be that much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I propose for+if.

```
Object result; 
for (Object o: objects){ 
  if (o.value3.equals("three")){ 
    result=o; 
    break;
  }
}
```

no streams, no guavas, I think it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list:

```
list.stream().filter(
              sample -> sample.getValue4().equals("4")
              ).forEach(System.out::println)
```