# How to look for exact same color in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of 24 colors. Occasionally when I generate it I get colors that have the exact same RGB values. What I want to do is find the duplicates in the array and change the value of the match by like 1 or 2. Just so that it doesn't match anymore.

Here is my array of colors. Notice that there are 3 of the exact shade of red. I want each one to be slightly different from each other. Keep the R channel the same but change the G and or B channels to be like 1 or 2 numbers higher.

```
Color Array: [java.awt.Color[r=255,g=194,b=23], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=67,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=175], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=13,b=10], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=115,b=43], java.awt.Color[r=2,g=92,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=241,g=219,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=194,b=0], java.awt.Color[r=231,g=210,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=43,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=80,b=0], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=205,b=27], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=9], java.awt.Color[r=205,g=199,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=44,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0], java.awt.Color[r=21,g=255,b=219], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=199,b=51], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=82,b=2], java.awt.Color[r=215,g=198,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=203], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=98,b=28]]
```

What I was thinking was iterating through the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++){
    if(colorArray[i] == //not sure what this would be equal to as it will be checking all the values in the array ) {
       colorArray[i].getBlue() =  matchingColor.getBlue() += 1;
       colorArray[i].getGreen()  matchingColor.getGreen() += 2; //These are example values just to make sure that they have no match
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use [`colorArray[i].equals(matchingColor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#equals(java.lang.Object))?

Comment: for my comparisons comparing the reference instead of the object seems to be working better. I am not opposed to it but would rather just compare the reference. @Tibrogargan

Comment: Why don't you generate them into some kind of `Set`, and stop when the `Set` has the right number of elements?

Comment: Also, it's possible to have two different `Color` objects with the same RGB values, so comparing the reference is no good.

Comment: `equals` does not do reference comparison, it is object implementation dependent.  In this case: **The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a Color object that has the same red, green, blue, and alpha values as this object.**

Comment: I don't want to remove the duplicates. I just want to find a match in the array and just change it slightly. @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: when you have found the Color using `equals` then replace the Object with the new Color Object

Comment: I can compare the actual object I just wasn't doing so at the time. @Tibrogargan I know that `equals` compares content and the `==` compares the reference. i stated I wasn't doing so at the time because I didn't run into it being a problem and I am not opposed to changing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learning the APIs of the Classes you use is really helpful.

```
for(int i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
    // use while in case the color is black/white.  (May thrash for few iterations)
    while (colorArray[i].equals(matchingColor)) {
       colorArray[i] = (Math.random() < 0.5)?colorArray[i].brighter():colorArray[i].darker();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I check if colorArray[i].equals  another color in the array?

Comment: To check for duplicates you're better off using a data type to store your elements that supports this sort of functionality.  A primitive array isn't terribly useful for this - you have to search the entire thing manually.  A set may be useful (as @DawoodibnKareem suggests)

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138990/how-to-search-in-a-list-of-java-object) first

Comment: I don't believe this will work in all cases.  When you modify `colorArray[i]`, you could be setting it to the same colour as something else in the array.  I'm assuming this is intended to sit inside a second loop, where `matchingColor` iterates through the colours in the array - so it's no good if `colorArray[i]` gets changed to a value that has _already been_ `matchingColor` on some iteration.

Comment: Nor does it work if you have a lot of the same color, since it could potentially end up in an endless loop.  Just using `brigher`/`darker` is an easy fix, but it's a step towards a good solution that covers all the edge cases.  Need to take care not to over-engineer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a `Set` to maintain uniqueness.  This saves re-inventing all the functionality to check for duplicates.  It takes advantage of the fact that the `add` method of the `Set` interface returns `true` if the object has been added to the set.  Under the covers, of course, it uses the `equals` method of `Color`.

In the event that a duplicate is found, we repeatedly try modifying the `Color` a little, by doing a bitwise exclusive-or of its three components,  until we come to a unique one.

```
public void deduplicate(Color[] colors) {
    Set<Color> uniqueColors = new HashSet<>();
    for (int which = 0; which < colors.length; which++) {
        Color originalColor = colors[which];
        boolean unique = uniqueColors.add(originalColor);
        for (int modifyBy = 1; !unique ; modifyBy++) {
            colors[which] = new Color(
                    originalColor.getRed() ^ modifyBy, 
                    originalColor.getGreen() ^ modifyBy, 
                    originalColor.getBlue() ^ modifyBy);
            unique = uniqueColors.add(colors[which]);
        }
    }
}
```