# Java library for searching and sorting JSON objects

Tags: java, json

I am getting a list of objects in JSON form. After storing this list I need to be able to search/sort this list by any attribute of it. For example, My data is product data, and products have a `price` attribute. Is there any library that helps with sorting by price and/or searching by product name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should decomposite task on few:

1. Parse  JSON data to java objects. [(`GSON` lib)](https://github.com/google/gson) [some examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java)
2. Sort list. It is simple task. For example  you can use `Collections.sort(List<T> var0, Comparator<? super T> var1)` from `java.util package`
   [some examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252269/how-to-sort-an-arraylist)
3. Search by list. It is simple task too. You can use for example `stream().filter`. [some examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138990/how-to-search-in-a-list-of-java-object)