# Multidimensional arrayList get ID and remove the entire list from the arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
class Emp {

    String ID, FName, LName, ASalary, StartDate;

    Emp(String _ID, String _FName, String _LName, String _ASalary, String _StartDate) {
        ID = _ID;
        FName = _FName;
        LName = _LName;
        ASalary = _ASalary;
        StartDate = _StartDate;
    }
}

ArrayList< Emp> Record = new ArrayList< Emp>();


 private void btnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String ID;

        ID = IDin.getText();
     
        int firstIndex = Record.indexOf(ID);
        Record.remove(firstIndex);
        Display.setText("remove " + ID + " Indext of " + firstIndex);
}
```

It returns -1 as it couldn't find ID in the ArrayList, I just need to get ID number and remove the entire ArrayList with that ID number

Comment: Your are storing EMP records but are searching use a String.

Comment: As per the javadocs *Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.*  If you have an ID of `Fred` it will not be found because Your list does not contain a String Object `Fred` - see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13139071/2310289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `removeIf` and provide a predicate like this:

```java
id = IDin.getText();
record.removeIf(emp -> emp.getId().equals(id)); //add null check if needed
```

[boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

> Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given
> predicate. Errors or runtime exceptions thrown during iteration or by
> the predicate are relayed to the caller.

Comment: You have to define a getter method inside `Emp` class:  `public String getId() {
        return id;
    }`